# unable to run redis-server as a service on centos

Tags: service, redis, centos7

On a centos 7 I installed redis using the regular wget, make and make install commands.

While I am able to do a command

```
$redis-server redis.conf
```

and it works nicely.

But if I try

```
systemctl start redis-server
```

or

```
sudo service redis-server start/restart
```

it says

```
Failed to issue method call: Unit redis-server.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
```

How can I fix this. I need to run redis-server as a service.

Answer (score 3):

You can try:

```
sudo systemctl enable redis-server 

sudo service redis-server start
```

You can check that redis or redis-server right. May be You need to restart Your System after sudo systemctl enable redis-server

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to install Redis via an RPM (package) rather than just performing a **wget** of the sources and building them.  You might find a suitable version in the "extra packages for Enterprise Linux" [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) collection.  Just add the appropriate repositories to your Yum configuration and use ***yum*** commands to update your package indexes and query them to see if you have the Redis server version you're interested in.  Here's a guide on [How to install redis server on CentOS 7 / RHEL 7](http://sharadchhetri.com/2014/10/04/install-redis-server-centos-7-rhel-7/) using EPEL

Another option would be to build your own RPM using a .spec file.  Rather than trying to write your own from scratch you might try something like [remicollet/remirepo's redis.spec](https://github.com/remicollet/remirepo/blob/master/redis/redis.spec) as a starting point (for version 3.0.7) or search around for other RPMs or .spec files. However the big deal is that you need the *redis.service* and *redis.init* configuration files that are used to describe how to run a Redis server to the **systemd** system.